# Dynamic HTML template to an email using sendgrid java

Tags: java, html, twilio, sendgrid, sendgrid-templates

I am using sendgrid java to send an e-mail where email is of HTML. And the html contains some dynamic content which comes as a request from the frontend.I have a text field on frontend where it contains some spaces and newlines(\n). If I send the text exactly to the java service where it maps the text to an html Template. In this whole process of feature, what to do if i want to get the line breaks on email html

I have tried using StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(text) in java to render it with line breaks but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `<br />` HTML tag for newlines?

Comment: No its not working with the <br/> even

Comment: Getting like this on mail when i replace "\n" with <br/> and send it - (Enter text if sharing new updates to an existing bulletin (context on what changed) or want to send out an ad-hoc message to specific entity(s) and or users)<br/>(Enter text if sharing new updates to an existing bulletin (i.e context on what changed) or want to send out an ad-hoc message to specific entity(s) and or users)

Comment: Note that the [<br>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-br-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. The same is true for all HTML tags.

Comment: Even with the br tag also not working! And I have also tried css property called white-space: pre-line but it works only on UI and when i send it to an API as a request then its not working